# Update and create a multi-dimensional dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am parsing JSON that stores various code snippets and I am first building a dictionary of languages used by these snippets:

```
snippets = {'python': {}, 'text': {}, 'php': {}, 'js': {}}
```

Then when looping through the JSON I'm wanting add the information about the snippet into its own dictionary to the dictionary listed above. For example, if I had a JS snippet - the end result would be:

```
snippets = {'js': 
                 {"title":"Script 1","code":"code here", "id":"123456"}
                 {"title":"Script 2","code":"code here", "id":"123457"}
}
```

Not to muddy the waters - but in PHP working on a multi-dimensional array I would just do the following (I am lookng for something similiar):

```
snippets['js'][] = array here
```

I know I saw one or two people talking about how to create a multidimensional dictionary - but can't seem to track down adding a dictionary to a dictionary within python. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is called [autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification):

You can do it with `defaultdict`

```
def tree():
    return collections.defaultdict(tree)

d = tree()
d['js']['title'] = 'Script1'
```

If the idea is to have lists, you can do:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
d['js'].append({'foo': 'bar'})
d['js'].append({'other': 'thing'})
```

The idea for defaultdict it to create automatically the element when the key is accessed. BTW, for this simple case, you can simply do:

```
d = {}
d['js'] = [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'other': 'thing'}]
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest, but from his second code snippet it looks like he wants 'js' to return a list of dicts.

Comment: @placeybordeaux I don't really like [php](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/), but I'm quite sure their "Array" object may behave as list or as a dict depending on the moon position or something like that...

Comment: I have no love for PHP, but I was referring to `snippets = {'js':{"id":"3"}{"id":"2"}}`, it looks like he wants a list of dicts attached to js, text, python etc. I love defaultdicts and even more so recursivily defined defaultdicts, but it looks like they won't work for exactly what he wants.

Comment: @placeybordeaux I thought he unintentionally pasted the line twice... Possibly a `defaultdict(list)` will solve the problem

Comment: yes, I do want multiple dictionaries within so I will take a look at defaultdict(list), if you would like to provide an example of that as well that would be great. It looks as though the answer by @placeybordeaux would do what I'm looking for but I like learning different methods of approach when learning a new language. Thanks.

Comment: why the bad karma for php - at least it handles autovivification natively without need to define a function before you can do anything :-)

Answer (score 8):

From

```
snippets = {'js': 
                 {"title":"Script 1","code":"code here", "id":"123456"}
                 {"title":"Script 2","code":"code here", "id":"123457"}
}
```

It looks to me like you want to have a list of dictionaries. Here is some python code that should hopefully result in what you want

```
snippets = {'python': [], 'text': [], 'php': [], 'js': []}
snippets['js'].append({"title":"Script 1","code":"code here", "id":"123456"})
snippets['js'].append({"title":"Script 1","code":"code here", "id":"123457"})
print(snippets['js']) #[{'code': 'code here', 'id': '123456', 'title': 'Script 1'}, {'code': 'code here', 'id': '123457', 'title': 'Script 1'}]
```

Does that make it clear?

Comment: Cool, do you need it explained more at all? Please remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem.